# Can arabic gum substitute for fat in making ice cream from homogenized 3% fat (low fat) milk

Tags: substitutions, milk, ice-cream

Many articles suggest adding gum to ice cream batter to make it creamy , can this technique be used to add more gum to the milk to compensate for the low fat homogenized milk. Mostly recipes ask to add full cream along with milk, so if we don't want such a heavy cream ice cream can this or possibly some other technique work to compensate for the lesser fat to ensure a creamy store like ice cream?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've tried this in ice cream, but a trick I picked up for sorbets (via looking at commercial product ingredient lists - *often boring and full of things you can't get at home, but sometimes there's a useful nugget hiding in there*) was to add pectin - the "regular" stuff, not the pink "low sugar" stuff (misleading - it's for "low sugar" canning, so it's mostly dextrose, or corn sugar - regular pectin is mostly pectin.) I'll use a tablespoon/15 ml for a 1.5 - 2 pint batch, and 3 Tablespoons/45 ml for a gallon batch (3 quarts liquid before freezing.)

Regular pectin mixes in quite nicely. The low sugar stuff is highly annoying (got a box by accident once - won't make that mistake again.)

I don't know if there's any compatibility issue with dairy (or not), I simply have never even thought to try it other than with sorbets/popsicles that are non-dairy. A quick look shows people using it to stiffen yogurt that isn't making it on it's own, so I think you'd be good there. For that matter, some lowfat/nonfat yogurt might also be a good ingredient for your lowfat ice "cream" attempts.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot comment on the use of arabic gum in ice cream recipes, I will share what I do to to help lower the fat in our homemade ice cream.  I use a combination of Fat Free Sweetened Condensed Milk, Low Fat (2%) Evaporated Milk (you can also substitute fat free half and half or low fat milk) and unflavored gelatin as a base.  Off of that base, my wife likes mocha chip (espresso powder, Kahlua and mini choc chips) and I like butter pecan.  The end result is surprisingly rich and creamy and significantly lower in fat than using heavy cream and whole milk.

Based on comments, I have added the following:  Both condensed milk and evaporated milk have had roughly 60% of the water removed.  The final product is thick and creamy and I believe it is what helps make up for the fat, although it is just an educated guess.  I have used unflavored gelatin in the past to help thicken depending on the recipe but as Ecnerwal suggested, pectin may work as well but I cannot confirm.

Comment: So.. you're replacing cream with sweetened condensed milk? Are you also reducing the sugar in the recipe?

Comment: Yes, I am replacing cream with fat free sweetened condensed milk (you can also use regular sweetened condensed milk if fat is no object.  Since the condensed milk is already sweetened, it depends on the final flavor profile you are going for and how sweet you want it.  I don't add any sugar for the mocha chip but for the butter pecan I add a brown sugar simple syrup and pecans for that butter pecan flavor.  The other benefit of this method is it is no churn meaning I just mix it all together and freeze.  If I am adding chips or nuts I partially freeze and then mix in so they stay distributed.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of ice cream recipes online that utilize condensed milk, fat free or regular, if one chooses to go this route :)

Comment: I'm asking about compared to a normal ice cream recipe with cream, milk, and sugar. It sounds like you're replacing the sugar *and* the cream with sweetened condensed milk, thus replacing fat and sugar with just sugar, i.e. you're just taking the fat out. It'd be good to be a bit more clear about that, because the OP is asking how to compensate for taking the fat out, and you're effectively saying "don't bother, just leave out the fat". (Also I'm a bit skeptical; in my experience that sort of substitution alters the texture, making it freeze harder.)

Comment: can you share the exact recipe with correct ingredients , can agar agar be used instead of gelatin?

Comment: @Jefromi..Since both condensed milk and evaporated milk have roughly 60% of the water removed, the thick creamy texture makes up for the lack of fat.  I think that the "hard freeze" would come to bare if using only a lower fat milk where the fat is decreased and the water content is increased.  I am by no means a scientist, only someone who enjoys ice cream and have found that both condensed milk products work well in my homemade ice cream.

Comment: @bread101....I am familiar with agar agar but have never used it.  I am a little leery because every time I see someone use it on Chopped they screw it up:).  As for your request for a recipe, I want to honor the rules of the site by not giving out a specific recipe.  My suggestion is to Google condensed milk ice cream recipes and adapt them to your specific taste and health requirements :)  I can only tell you that once I got my recipes down, my family and friends were delighted and ask me to make it more often than I should :)